# Sortable with jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, coldfusion

I have data that I am accessing via ajax from a Coldfusion component. I am trying to display the data in a sortable jQuery ui format but the sortable feature is not working. Here is the code I am trying to use.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // get assets to display
    var showid = <cfoutput>'#SESSION.Show#'</cfoutput>;
    var html = "";

    function assetsPost() {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type:'POST',
            url:'cfc/cfc_COLF.cfc?method=qCOLF&returnformat=json',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
              show_id:    showid
            },
            success:function(data) {
                if(data && data.length) {   // DO SOMETHING 

                         html += "<ul id='sortable'>";

                jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {    
                     var linkID         = data[i].linkID;
                     var description    = data[i].description;
                     var discussion     = data[i].discussion;
                     var linkurl        = data[i].linkurl;
                     var index          = i;
                         html += "<li id=' " + index + " ' class='ui-state-default'>";                  
                         html += "<h5 style='color:#000; text-align:left;'>";
                         html += "<a class='process-asset' id=' " + linkID + " ' name='done'><img src='images/icon_done.png'></a>";
                         html += "<a href='" + linkurl + "' target='_blank'> " + description + "</a>";
                         html += "<a class='process-asset' id=' " + linkID + " ' name='remove' style='color:#000; float:right;'><img src='images/icon_remove.png'></a>";
                         html += "</h5>";
                         html += "<p style='color:#000; margin:5px 15px 5px 15px; text-align:left;'> " + discussion + "</p>";
                         html += "</li>";
                });
                         html += "</ul>";

                 $('#linkoutput').html( html );
                 //alert(html);
                } else { // DO SOMETHING 
                }
            }
        });
    }  
    assetsPost(); 
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
        //sort order 
      $(function() {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            opacity: 0.6,
            update: function(event, ui) {
             var Order = $("#sortable").sortable('toArray').toString();
          $('#order').val(Order);
            //alert(Order);
            }
        });
            $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
    // set up sort order for form submission
    $("#mForm").submit(function() {
        $("#order").val($("#sortable").sortable('toArray'))
  });  
});
```

All the data and the jQuery is loading just fine. In fact, if I added the following code and this list sorts just fine.

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="1" class="ui-state-default ">
      <h5>1</h5>
  </li>
  <li id="2" class="ui-state-default ">
      <h5>2</h5>
  </li>
  <li id="3" class="ui-state-default ">
      <h5>3</h5>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**HTML** UPDATED

Here is the HTML that I am using that isn't working

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  
  ACTION="page.cfm?#cgi.QUERY_STRING#" 
  id="mForm" 
  method="post">
  <fieldset>
  <div id="linkoutput"></div>

  <label>Order:</label> <input type="text" id="order" />
  <div class="mfInfo"></div>
  </div>

  </fieldset> 
</form>
```

So there has to be some sort of conflict in the ajax section of code. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What *isn't* working for you? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. The sortable feature is not working. I edited the original post.

Comment: Need some example response data to do testing of a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your example code seems to be missing or incorrect. I have reviewed it and created the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hfdg5y20/

**HTML**

```
<div class='sort-wrap'>
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li id="1" class="ui-state-default ">
      <h5>1</h5>
    </li>
    <li id="2" class="ui-state-default ">
      <h5>2</h5>
    </li>
    <li id="3" class="ui-state-default ">
      <h5>3</h5>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<label>Order:</label> <input type="text" id="order" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // get assets to display
  //var showid = < cfoutput > '#SESSION.Show#' < /cfoutput>;
  var showid = 10000000001;
  var html = "";

  function assetsPost() {
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/echo/json/',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        show_id: showid,
        json: JSON.stringify([{
          'linkID': 4,
          'description': "stuff",
          'discussion': "thread",
          'linkurl': "http://www.example.com/"
        }])
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data && data.length) { // DO SOMETHING 

          //html += "<ul id='sortable'>";
          var html = "";

          jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
            var linkID = data[i].linkID;
            var description = data[i].description;
            var discussion = data[i].discussion;
            var linkurl = data[i].linkurl;
            var index = $("#sortable li").length + 1;
            html += "<li id='" + index + "' class='ui-state-default'>";
            html += "<h5 style='color:#000; text-align:left;'>";
            html += "<a class='process-asset' id=' " + linkID + " ' name='done'><img src='images/icon_done.png'></a>";
            html += "<a href='" + linkurl + "' target='_blank'> " + description + "</a>";
            html += "<a class='process-asset' id=' " + linkID + " ' name='remove' style='color:#000; float:right;'><img src='images/icon_remove.png'></a>";
            html += "</h5>";
            html += "<p style='color:#000; margin:5px 15px 5px 15px; text-align:left;'> " + discussion + "</p>";
            html += "</li>";
          });
          //html += "</ul>";
          console.log(html);

          $('#sortable').append(html);
          $("#order").val($("#sortable").sortable('toArray'));
          //alert(html);
        } else { // DO SOMETHING 
        }
      }
    });
  }
  assetsPost();

  $("#sortable").sortable({
    opacity: 0.6,
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var Order = $("#sortable").sortable('toArray').toString();
      $('#order').val(Order);
      //alert(Order);
    }
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
  // set up sort order for form submission
  $("#mForm").submit(function() {
    $("#order").val($("#sortable").sortable('toArray'));
  });
});
```

This is using the jsfiddle method to mimic AJAX to show the working code. Yours will be a bit different and may have different results depending on the data that is returned.

The new item is appended to the end of the list. I did not find `$('#linkoutput')` in your HTML, so I appended to `$('#sortable')`. You can grab and sort the new item in the list just like the others. Understand that sortable will not arrange the items for you but allow the user to reorder them at will. See more: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: You will also want to avoid multiple `id` attributes that are not unique. Here are some other updates if you care to try them out: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hfdg5y20/9/

Comment: this is really good stuff Twisty. I have implemented your changes and the sortable function now works! One more issue and we should be good to go. The order that is in the form field is all 1's. In other words, my order looks like this "   1,1,1,1,1  ". I have will update the post with the html since I did add it from the beginning. Would like to here your thoughts.

Comment: NOTE: I left the linkoutput id in the HTML so that other visitors will not get confused when viewing later. What worked for me is when I replaced the "linkoutput" id with "sortable"

Comment: OH!>>> I GOT IT. Thanks Twisty

Comment: Great! Sounds like you found and figured it all out. You can always use different ids and selectors as you like. I just make them as sensible as I can for myself.

Answer (score 3):

You are making the list sortable, which changes the list and its elements, and then later replacing that list once your callback returns. You need to move your `$("#sortable").sortable({ ...` code into your success callback, *after* you've inserted the new list.

Comment: do you suggest that I put the $("#sortable").sortable({ ... after the $('#linkoutput').html( html );? I tried this and it still does not work. I am a little new to this so bear with me.

Comment: Update with your latest code. Make sure that there isn't another item with the "sortable" id on it.

Comment: I am still not catching this. I moved the sortable function after the success:function(data) { and it does not work. The sortable list that is outside the callback still works if I add it back.

Comment: Yo may need to update your code again. In what I see, the code which initializes the sortable list still isn't getting rerun in your `success` callback. Each time you manually recreate the html for that list, you are destroying all the sortable work, and need to redo it.

Comment: You could use the `$("#sortable").sortable('refresh');`   in the Ajax success callback.